# What to do with useful comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comment-flags

The comment on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33701344/3100115) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699193/find-documents-by-the-number-of-embedded-array-elements-that-match-condition) is so useful that I think it should be part of the answer. Can I edit the answer to add the comment and flag it as obsolete?

Comment: You could edit it in, but be sure to provide attribution to who posted it.

Comment: As alternative to immediately flagging "obsolete" consider comment like "I've updated post with info you've suggested, please see if it aligns with your suggestion." (consider to delete comment/flag whole thread after several days)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Editing your answers to increase their quality is always encouraged. You should however always provide attribution if you use content provided by comments or other answers. It would go something like this:

> As @User pointed out, this is an important caveat/addition to my
>   answer:
>
> [Text]

Its important that you do this because:

- Its fair
- It clears you of accusations of plagiarism
- Its common decency
- The Stack Exchange license requires attribution

If you want to go a step further (if the content you are editing in makes out the main part of the answer or the answer would otherwise make no sense) or if you have bad feelings about earning rep with someone else's content, you can always turn your post into a community wiki aswell. Keep in mind if you do this the answer becomes open to even content edits and you no longer own it.

I don't think flagging the comment for obsolescence is necessary, since even when edited in, its still pertaining to the Answer.

Comment: *It clears you of accusations of plagiarism* - That's important. Always give credit to the right person / resource. As long as an answer contains the words - *as @user says*, it is OK

Comment: I think it's the nice, decent thing to do, as you point out, but I'm not sure I agree with the bit about the SE License. This seems to imply that if the author of a comment complained you had included it in their answer without attribution, they could claim copyright and force a rollback or something. Surely not.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist well, in principle they could send a formal DMCA complaint to SE, after which the SE people would force a rollback and purge the allegedly offending revision from the database. Unless the answer's author provides a formal counternotice, in which case it falls to a court to decide whether the rollback is necessary. I'm sure it's exceedingly rare, possibly unprecedented, that any commenter would consider this worth the effort.